# Exclude admin from the top commenters list

Tags: admin, exclude

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Top Commenters: exclude admin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/34251/top-commenters-exclude-admin)

While back I found this hack here to display top commenters.
It works fine. But I would like to exclude the admin from the commenters list. So Please help modify the code to exclude the admin Thanks.

The code is:

```
function top_comment_authors($amount = 5) { 

    global $wpdb;  
    $results = $wpdb->get_results(' 
        SELECT 
            COUNT(comment_author_email) AS comments_count, comment_author_email, comment_author, comment_author_url 
        FROM 
            '.$wpdb->comments.' 
        WHERE 
            comment_author_email != "" AND comment_type = "" AND comment_approved = 1 
        GROUP BY 
            comment_author_email 
        ORDER BY 
            comments_count DESC, comment_author ASC 
        LIMIT '.$amount  
    );  
$output = "<ul>"; 
    foreach($results as $result){ 
        $output .= "<li>".(($result->comment_author_url) ? "<a href='".$result->comment_author_url."'>" : "").$result->comment_author.(($result->comment_author_url) ? "</a>" : "")." (".$result->comments_count.")</li>"; 


    } 
    $output .= "</ul>";  
    echo $output;  
}
```

Comment: found the simple and straightforward answer here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/34251/top-commenters-exclude-admin

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the comment_author is a User ID, try:

```
if(user_can($result->comment_author,'manage_options')){
    $output .= "<li>".(($result->comment_author_url) ? "<a href='".$result->comment_author_url."'>" : "").$result->comment_author.(($result->comment_author_url) ? "</a>" : "")." (".$result->comments_count.")</li>";
}
```

If not, one can use `get_comment`, and select the `comment_ID` in the SQL statement. You can then use the object returned to grab the user ID of the comments author, and do a check to see if they are an administrator using the `user_can` function from above.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comment

edit:

1. you need to the comment_ID. Modify your SQL query to retrieve this.
2. inside the foreach loop, call get_comment which will return you a comment object. For an example see [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comment)
3. From this comment object, grab the user ID of the commenter and assign it to a variable
4. call user_can, passing the user ID you got in step 3. you need to check if the user can change options, which only an administrator can do, so we pass in 'manage_options' as the second parameter
5. if user_can returns false, list the comment
6. if user_can returns true, skip to the next comment, this is an administrator comment

Comment: Thanks for your time and help. I am really lost and don't know how and where to insert your code into my code. I tried different ways but no result. So, please rewrite my code with your mod so that it excludes the admin. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Replace what's inside the for loop. You should read up on what I've linked however in order to understand what my code is doing.

Comment: Also you will need to add `comment_ID ` to the SQL statement SELECT

Comment: I wish I new what you are talking about. I have noidea. Anyway, I want to thank you for your time and trying to help me.

Comment: there is a foreach loop in your code, take what is inside it, delete it and replace it with my code

Comment: Did you write the code in your question yourself?

Comment: I tried replacing this line foreach($results as $result){ with this if(user_can($result->comment_author,'manage_options')){ and that did not help.

Comment: I've modified the answer to explain what needs doing. If you are looking for someone to do your work for you, I suggest you look for a developer, 1 hour of their time should be more than enough to type up this and any other things you need. Keep in mind this site is for questions and answers, not developer time

Comment: No, I said replace the inside of the foreach, not the foreach itself!!!

Comment: Tom, I did not write the code in my question. As I said I found it here in this forum while back and it works great. All I want to do is just exclude admin from the commenters list.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1801/discussion-between-tom-j-nowell-and-t-p)

Comment: continue in chat