# Top Commenters: exclude admin

Tags: comments

I'm using the following code in my function.php to display the top commenters in my theme:

```
function top_comment_authors($amount = 5){

    global $wpdb;

    $results = $wpdb->get_results('
        SELECT
            COUNT(comment_author_email) AS comments_count, comment_author_email, comment_author, comment_author_url
        FROM
            '.$wpdb->comments.'
        WHERE
            comment_author_email != "" AND comment_type = "" AND comment_approved = 1
        GROUP BY
            comment_author_email
        ORDER BY
            comments_count DESC, comment_author ASC
        LIMIT '.$amount

    );

    $output = "<ul>";
    foreach($results as $result){
    $output .= "<li>".get_avatar($result->comment_author_email, 30).' <p>'.(($result->comment_author_url) ? "<a href='".$result->comment_author_url."'>" : "").$result->comment_author.(($result->comment_author_url) ? "</a>" : "")." (".$result->comments_count.")</p></li>";
    }
    $output .= "</ul>";

    echo $output;
}
```

It works fine, but I'd like to **exclude** myself, aka the **admin**/author. 
Is this possible at all? If so, how would I do that? In what way would I have to modify the code above?

Thanks a lot in advance! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extend the WHERE clause:

```
WHERE
    comment_author_email != "" 
    AND comment_author_email != "YOUR_MAIL_ADDRESS" 
    AND comment_type = "" 
    AND comment_approved = 1 
)
```

If you want to exclude multiple email addresses, use the `NOT IN` operator and a comma separated list of strings:

```
AND comment_author_email NOT IN ( "hello@example.com", "world@example.com" )
```

Comment: How to exclude multiple email addresses?

Comment: @Bikram See my update. :)

Answer (score -1):

comment_author_email is fine but as far as I'm concerned I prefer using user id :

```
AND user_id!="1"
```

It should do the job !

Comment: User ID 1 is not necessary an admin; it doesn't even have to exist.

Comment: you're right :/