# See some statistics about the comments

Tags: comments, statistics

Is there a way or a plugin so that I can see statistics for may comments and commenters? Like top commenters, most commented post, etc.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

For most commented posts you can use a custom loop in the sidebar for example:

```
<h3>Most Commented Posts</h3>

<?php $most_commented = new WP_Query('orderby=comment_count&posts_per_page=5');

if($most_commented->have_posts()) : ?>

<ul class="most-commented-posts">

<?php while($most_commented->have_posts()) : $most_commented->the_post(); ?>    

    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?> (<?php comments_number('0','1','%'); ?>)</a></li>

<?php endwhile; ?>

</ul><!-- most-commented-posts -->

<?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

For the top commenters you can use something like this:

[Top Commenters: exclude admin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/34251/top-commenters-exclude-admin)

And for comment stats like total comments, etc. use this function:

```
function comment_stats() {
    global $wpdb;

    // approved responses (comments and trackbacks) 
    $comment_stats['total_responses'] = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->comments WHERE comment_approved = '1'");

    // trackback count
    $comment_stats['total_trackbacks'] = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->comments WHERE comment_type = 'pingback' OR comment_type = 'trackback'");

    // comments count
    $comment_stats['total_comments'] = $comment_stats['total_responses'] - $comment_stats['total_trackbacks'];


   // Akismet spam captured
   if(function_exists('akismet_count')) {

              $comment_stats['spam_blocked'] = akismet_count();

  }

  if(!empty($comment_stats)) {

  $html .= "<ul class=\"comments-stats\">\n";

  foreach($comment_stats as $stat => $stat_value) :

       if(isset($stat_value) && $stat_value > 0) {

             $stat_name = str_replace("_", " ", $stat);

                           $html .= "<li>" .ucwords($stat_name). " : " .number_format($stat_value). "</li>\n";

       }

  endforeach;

  $html .= "</ul>\n";

  echo $html;

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Admin comments statistics plugin ( http://www.greatwpplugins.com/admin-comments-statistics/ ). I can see statistics for my post comments and users. Also I can see statistics for the blog admins, so I can see my activity on my blog. I recommend.

Regards,

Dora