# How to get last comments but not from admin (or other specific user role/capability)?

Tags: comments, comments-template

I'm using [get_comments](http://codex.wordpress.org/get_comments) to show lastest comments i.e.:

```
<?php
    global $comments, $comment;
    $comments = get_comments( array( 'number' => '5', 'status' => 'approve', 'post_status' => 'publish' ) );

    foreach ( (array) $comments as $comment) {
     echo '<li>'.$comment->comment_author.' said '.$comment->comment_content .'</li>'
    }
;?>
```

Is there some way to override admin comments?! I know [this tip](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/34251/top-commenters-exclude-admin) using SQL but maybe Im'missing something in this function?

Thanks for help.

**Updated code**
Place this code wherever template file such `sidebar.php`, `footer.php` and will list latest comments (displaying Admin comments tough).

Comment: You can use the action `pre_get_comments` to filter out the admin comments.

Answer (score 2):

### Yay! We got filters!

Wrapping the result of the `$wpdb` comments query right into a filter callback (and a plugin) is the nice way of handling comments.

```
/* Plugin Name: »Kaisers« Comments without admin comments */
! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) AND exit;

add_filter( 'comments_array', 'wpse_61072_comments_without_admin', 20, 2 );
function wpse_61072_comments_without_admin( $comments, $post_id )
{
    foreach ( (array) $comments as $index => $c )
    {
        // Add a limit
        if ( 5 <= absint( $index + 1 ) )
            return (object) $comments;

        // Get the authors user data
        $author = get_userdata( $c->user_id );
        // Unset based on the standard/default capability
        if ( user_can( $author->ID, 'manage_options' ) )
            unset( $comments[ $index ] );
    }

    return (object) $comments;
}
```

This one *should* work (not tested).

Comment: I'm sorry, your plugin is not working here :( is still displaying admin comments wherever I use `get_comments`. I just want display latest comments in some areas then I created a function in `function.php`(not a plugin, just a theme).

Comment: I think there's type - `unset( $comments[ $index ]; )`

Comment: @amit Many many thanks! :) I just didn't see it and currently have no dev env, where I got comments. Just a sidenote: You can always fell free to go into my answers and edit them (like you do with all those questions ;) ).

Comment: @Diana Typo fixed (props amit) - give it a try and report back please.

Comment: Still no luck :( Is not working. I get `syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR, expecting ')'` in line 'function wpse_61072_comments_without_admin( $comments, $post->ID )'. I removed `$post->ID`, no errors but admin comments are stil showing. Why use `$post->ID`?

Comment: Yeah, that's fixed too now. I simply copy/pasted the values from the filter source and completely oversaw that it is accessing the post objects ID. Try it again.

Answer (score 1):

> ### Note -
>
> It uses the values stored in global variable - `wp_query`. Usually the `wp_query` variable contains comments of current post when browsing.

**Usage -**

```
$comments = wpse61072_hide_admin_comment(5); // 5=max comments
foreach  ( $comments as $comment ) {
    echo '<li>'.$comment->comment_author.' - said : '.$comment->comment_content.'</li>';
    
}
```

**Functions.php -**

```
/*
 * Usage : $comments = wpse61072_hide_admin_comment($post->ID, 5);      
 * Show Count : echo count(wpse61072_hide_admin_comment($post->ID, 5));     
 
 * This goes into functions.php 
*/
function wpse61072_hide_admin_comment ( $post_id, $no ) {
    global $wp_query; // uses global variable
    $woa_comments = $wp_query->comments;
    
    //thanks @kaiser for loop
    foreach ( $woa_comments as $woa_comment => $woac ) {    
        $author = get_userdata( $woac->user_id );
        if (user_can( $author, 'manage_options' )) {    
            unset( $woa_comments[ $woa_comment ] );
        }
    }
    
    //make sure we're returing only specified elements
    return (array_slice($woa_comments,0,$no));          
}
```

<sup>- Tested on **wordpress 3.4.1** with **TwentyTen** theme.</sup>

Comment: This would work if you don't mind the number of comments being inconsistant.  ie: your pulling 5 comments before filtering, if admin is the author of 2, you'll end up only displaying 3 comments.

Comment: You are right. I didn't think about that.

Comment: Yes, works but something I get 0 comments then :D thanks anyway

Comment: Updated answer with new example, uses - foreach loop by @kaiser.

Answer (score 1):

Totally untested, but you should be able to use the pre_get_comments filter:

```
 function exclude_admin_comments($query) {
    $query->query_vars['user_id'] != 1;
  }

  add_action('pre_get_comments', 'exclude_admin_comments');
```

Comment: :( Did anything here, placed right before the function in functions.php. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, the `pre_get_comments()` hook is used to change the args supplied to get_comments() functions.